# Realted to Telerik Rad Grid design

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I want to Design something like this

Suppose

there 3 row with some header and under each row mutiple rows are there

Rate  3.5

Text Image Text

Score 2.4

Text Image Text

Quanity 1.5

Text Image Text

Answer (score 0):

You can set up grouping expression for rows and customize header-row-of-grouped-childrow to show custom-text like "Rate 3.5" or "Score 2.4" or "Quanity 1.5".

To customize header-row-of-grouped-childrow, override onitemcreated event of RadGrid and check if e.Item.ItemType == Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemType.GroupHeader to add custom-text